# Правильно ли используеться UNIQUE KEY

Tags: mysql

Пусть есть три таблици: студенты, жилье и еще какая - то.
В жилье поля: `id` автоинкрементированное, `town`, `street`, `flat_number`.
Чтобы запись в жилье не повторялась следует сделать **UNIQUE KEY (id, town, street, flat_number)** и правильно ли я написал? После этого создаем PK (`id`) и таким образом могут в третей таблици уже быть ссылки на записи из жилья и не буде ошибок,как если бы в жилье я создал два первичных ключа?
Второе. А если бы не было третей таблици со ссылками, можно бы ло сделать через PRIMARY KEY, а не UNIQUE KEY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял то: нет unique key должын быть другим.

Должно быть: `UNIQUE KEY (town, street, flat_number)` иначе строки с одинаковыми `town, street, flat_number` могут повторятся с разными id.

"Как если бы в жилье я создал два первичных" - таблицы не могут иметь двух первичных ключей, но вы можете эмулировать первичный ключ. PRIMARY KEY это тоже смое что и UNIQUE + NOT NULL. Если вам нужно эмулировать первичный ключ то можете навесить на это поле/поля unique и not null (not null должны быть все поля в ключе).

"Второе. А если бы не было третей таблици со ссылками, можно бы ло сделать через PRIMARY KEY, а не UNIQUE KEY" --- если вам не нужна уникальность по жилью, и таблица студентов приведена просто так (она не зависит ни от жилья ни от 3ей таблицы), то да. Но зачем, в таком случае, в вопросе упомянута таблица студентов если от неё ничего не зависит?

Comment: а ведь можно id записи в жилье убрать, нам ведь подразумевается, что одна запись закреплена за одним студентом?

Comment: С точки зрения реляционной алгебры `id` - бессмысленное поле. Первичным ключом являются (town, street и flat_number), другие поля если и есть то зависят не от id а от этих 3 пролей. Id, в подобных таблицах, используется для  ускорения join и некоторых выборок (слить 2 тиблицы по 1 колонки с int проще чем по 3 строкам) и для удобства программиста (по тем же причинам проще делать обновления и удаления отдельных строк).

Comment: Понял спасибо, за Ваш ответ)